# JS/HTML5 - Basic setup for multi-version of a website according to operating systems?

Tags: javascript, html

what i mean is 
how to set up the page so like

```
if (android(session) = true && ios(session) = true ) 
{
//display tablet and smartphone version
} else
{
if (desktop() true || windows() = true)
{
//display desktop version
}
if (desktop() true || windows() = true&& browser = ie+9, javascript enabled)
{
//display desktop version
}
{

}
```

i know this is not real code but it gives insight on the basic code layout i need

can you help me on this one or share a link thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [*viewport metadata*](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/#the-atviewport-rule) might be what you are looking for.
Here is a good read (especially since you are trying to support android too) on the [android dev site](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html#Metadata).

From that doc:

```
<meta name="viewport"
      content="
          height = [pixel_value | device-height] ,
          width = [pixel_value | device-width ] ,
          initial-scale = float_value ,
          minimum-scale = float_value ,
          maximum-scale = float_value ,
          user-scalable = [yes | no] ,
          target-densitydpi = [dpi_value | device-dpi |
                               high-dpi | medium-dpi | low-dpi]
          " />
```

You might also want to read up on [responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) as it kind of fits right in there.

Note: I believe that this is more appropriate as you probably only need to really determine the original browser if you want to incorporate the native look and feel for that platform. For making things *look right* going by width/height, scale, and density should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would do it by screen width using a code such as this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  if (screen.width >=600<=800) {
    window.location = "http://android.domain.com";
  }
 if (screen.width >=200<=300) {
    window.location = "http://os.domain.com";
  }
  //-->
</script>
```

Or, you can use a similar script but instead, change the css instead of the window location

Comment: Hopefully you'd also preserve the pathname, lest you [end up like this](http://xkcd.com/869/).